# How to extract json objects into an external file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this small code example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var texts = [{key:'key_1', value:'value_1'}, 
                 {key:'key_2', value:'value_2'},
                 {key:'key_3', value:'value_3'}];               
</script>
```

I use a json array directly in my xhtml page by using the script tag. The json array "texts" is used by an another java script function in my xhtml page, but that is not important at the moment.

How can a extract this json array into an external file? Which library it must be used?

EDIT:

I use a java maven project and that should be include my external json file!

I tried this code but it doesn´t work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var placeholderTexts = himjQuery(document).getJSON('placeholder.json');         
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to parse the json?.

Comment: No, i only want to create to json objects in a external file to get a smaller xhtml page and to get a better control about the json objects

Comment: http://jaskokoyn.com/2013/07/24/external-json-file/

Comment: I will not work with ajax, i want to get only a external json file and include it in a java script context

Answer (score 0):

You can use each loop in jQuery

Just try this

```
$.each(texts, function(key, value) {   }
```

Comment: but that is not a creating in an external file

Answer (score 0):

please try the below.

```
var arraysel;
var json = { };

for(var i = 0, l = arraysel.length; i < l; i++) {
  json[arraysel= [i].id] = arraysel= [i].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading many times your question, I think what you want is this:

- Create a .js file, for example `data.js`, with your data... which is not a JSON-serialized object, but a real literal. Use pure JSON notation if you want.

  ```
  var DATA = {"a":1, "b":2};
  ```
- Import that "script" wherever you want to use your data.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./data.js></script>
  ```
- Use this data from any place in your JS code, for instance:

  ```
  console.log(DATA.a);
  ```

Comment: I think your solution couldn´t be worked. I use my variable "texts" in that way: himjQuery(document).ready(function() {myMethod(texts);});

Comment: Of course it can be used, as long as you load the `data.js` file. Using my example, you would call `myMethod(DATA);`

Comment: a have postponed all code in my external js file. Is this the right way? In that it is usable

Comment: If this is what you mean: yeah, javascript code is normally better out of the html document. That way it is easier to maintain, and you can use it in different places.

Comment: But now i have the same problem. The Json File and js code are not cutting from each other. The problem ist, that my json file must be look like this:  var texts = [{key:'key_1', value:'value_1'}, 
                 {key:'key_2', value:'value_2'},
                 {key:'key_3', value:'value_3'}];

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Create a literal object/array in the `data.js` file, import that file, and then `texts` will be a global variable accessible from any part of your code (as long as you imported the .js file before)

Answer (score 0):

Please get JSON data from AJAX and evaluate response and store in variable

```
<script>
var placeholderTexts = new Object();
$(function(){
    $.get('placeholder.json', function(data){
              try{
                placeholderTexts  = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(placeholderTexts)
             }catch(e){
              alert(e.toString());
             }
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery has JSON methods already, it does not make sense to do an unsafe eval.